# Questions about antique objects

Tags: discussion

When [asking my question regarding a possibly antique object](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/epoch-of-an-item-with-anchor-symbol-with-the-letters-n-and-d) I reduced it to asking for the meaning of the logo and (if any) its historical meaning.

In reality I would have preferred to ask for more information. Material, usage of ivory for this kind of object, how to determine whether it is ivory and questions like this.

Is, in contrast to my understanding, history.SE the right place to ask this kind of questions?

If not, should it be?

If not, would it be worth launch an antique.SE where people can ask questions of antiques and their origin (not their value)?

A new proposal on Area 51 for Antiques: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80654/antiques

Comment: Asking about the usage of ivory for that type of object would be on-topic, but I really don't think asking how to determine what it is made of is on-topic.

Comment: Looks similar to the concerns raised here http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/468/2140

Answer (score 1):

Questions on this site should be about objects and events of historical significance. Your antique object, with the letters ND has religious, and therefore historical significance. Your question qualifies.

I consider the follow up about the use of ivory  "borderline" but it still qualifies. Ivory was a rare and valuable material, with implications for trade, and ultimately the crusades. But since this is "borderline," a third question about how to determine it would be even more "borderline" and probably off topic.

But a question about "how was Gutenberg's printing press made?" would be on topic since the printing press has HUGE historical significance.

Comment: FYI - I paraphrased this answer in [Are questions about antique objects in scope at History.se?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/) at Area51.